# Upload image to google Colab, and use Keras to predict the classification

Tags: python, image, opencv, keras, google-colaboratory

I trained a neural network model and I'd like to be able to easily upload an image from my computer to predict its classification.  I'm trying to upload an image to Google Colab using this code snippet:

```
from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():
  print('User uploaded file "{name}" with length {length} bytes'.format(
      name=fn, length=len(uploaded[fn])))
```

I'd like to use the `cv2.imread` function from the OpenCV module to convert the image into an array of pixels, but the uploaded file type is  bytes whereas this function requires a file path.

My question is, is there a way to save the uploaded image in the Colab's file directory so I can use it with the `cv2.imread` function as a file path or, is there  another way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reading byte array from memory try [cv2.imdecode](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imdecode#cv2.imdecode). Will need to convert the bytes to numpy array using np.frombuffer and then use imdecode

```
 img = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(uploaded[fn]), np.uint8), 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I just tried it but I got an error 'TypeError: buf is not a numpy array, neither a scalar'